# Why was Quark treated disrespectfully in Deep Space 9 given that he used to be Grand Nagus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, quark

Grand Nagus is the top political leader of the Ferengis. Quark was briefly the Grand Nagus. As such, he should be accorded high respect and good treatment when he operated the bar in DS9. Imagine if ex-President Obama opened a bar in China. I am sure the Chinese, from the ordinary citizens to their top leaders, will treat Obama with deep respect even if he is no longer President of the United States. Quark was treated disrespectfully by Sisko and Odo on several occasions. They do not talk to him politely.

How can this happen given that this seems out of line for DS9 as a matter of diplomatic protocol?

Comment: Bartender, I served with Zek. I knew Zek. Zek was a friend of mine. Bartender, you're no Zek.

Comment: To pick a possibly more relevant presidential example, imagine if Trump opened a bar in China after his term.  Given how nobody here seems to treat him with respect, would we expect anyone in China to?

Comment: Given the circumstances of Quark becoming Nagus, I'd say he was less Obama and more Millard Fillmore.

Comment: @Hellion: more like if Trump were removed from the Presidency tomorrow, and then opened (or re-opened) a bar.

Comment: I would love to read Quark's Twitter.

Comment: @1252748: Odo: you stole the command codes! Quark: I have some alternative facts about that for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quark was temporarily appointed Grand Nagus by the previous incumbent, Zek, purely to test how suitable Zek’s son, [Krax](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Krax), was to one day assume the position himself.

So, even assuming that former Grand Naguses (Nagi?) should be accorded respect, Quark is a pretty special case: he was never intended to be Grand Nagus on anything but a temporary and deceptive basis.

I also don’t remember Sisko being impolite to Quark. Odo, sure, but he plays by his own rules in any case — he’s not a member of Starfleet, and he never even seems particularly embedded in Bajor’s military. Whereas Sisko, from what I remember, generally treats Quark in a manner appropriate to Quark’s behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The Ferengi aren't especially well-respected, and while it is a whole planet, yes, the position would actually be the equivalent of an ex-leader of a small country who was only in power for about a week before he was deposed.

The culture of the Chinese would mean that, yes, even a temporary leader of prestige would be treated with respect. But the Federation doesn't work that way. It's more...individualistic.

Respect doesn't just come from a rank you used to have, but from what you did with it. If you were an ex-ambassador temporarily, and then you weren't, you might not be respected by them--but if you are currently an ambassador, that's different. And, if you're ex-ambassador Sarek, for instance, your long and storied resume will afford you respect.

Answer (score 2):

A better analogy would be if a scoundrel like President Robert Mugabe of Zimbabwe were operating a bar in some other part of the world. The assumption would be that he was up to shenanigans and that he should be treated with skepticism.

Answer (score 1):

Ferenginar wasn't a member of the Federation and the Federation had no diplomatic relationship with the Ferengi Alliance, which was simply considered neutral throughout the galaxy.

Comment: But China isn't a member of the United States either, so I don't think Ferenginar's diplomatic relation with the Federation is particularly relevant, given the example in the question.

Comment: “the Federation had no diplomatic relationship with the Ferengi Alliance” — none? Really?